# Number of solutions to a "quadratic equation"

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

> Suppose $Y(f)$ denotes the number of mutually incongruent solutions
> $(x,y)$ of the congruence $y^2\equiv f(x)\pmod{p}$ ($p$ an odd prime),
> where $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integral coefficients. Prove that
> $$Y(f)=p+\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{f(n)}{p}\right).$$ Note: Two
> solutions $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are said to be mutually
> incongruent if either $x_1\neq x_2$ or $y_1\neq y_2\pmod{p}$, or both.

My attempt:
$p+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{f(n)}{p}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{p-1} \left(1+({{f(x)}\over p})\right)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{p-1} c(x)$
Now $c(x)=0$ if $f(x)$ is not a square mod $p$, it is 1 if $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ and it is 2 if $f(x)$ is a nonzero square mod $p$. I don't know whether this can be equal to $Y(f)$? Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.
PS: I also found this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564493/quadratic-residues) but it does not answer me!

Comment: Actually that link _does_ answer you. You should clarify what part you don't understand.